# Submit button not working,form having 2 submit buttons but only one works

Tags: php, html, button, submit

This is my php code for home page

```
<section>                        
                        <form method="post" action="searchResVehicle.php">
                            <div class="content content-3">
                                <div class="title">Vehicle details</div>
                                    <div class="v-3col-container">
                                        <div class="v-3col">
                                            <label for="">Code</label>
                                            <input type="text" id="v-code" name="v-code">                                        
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="v-3col">
                                                <label for="vehicleSelector">Type</label>
                                                <select id="vehicleSelector" name="vehicle_selector">
                                                    <option value="car">Car</option>
                                                    <option value="van">Van</option>
                                                </select> 
                                                <button type="submit" name="searchVehicle">Search</button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="v-3col">
                                            <label for="">Model</label>
                                            <input type="text" id="v-model" name="v-model" readonly>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="v-3col-container">
                                        <div class="v-3col">
                                            <label for="">Free Milage (LKR)</label>
                                            <input type="text" id="v-FreeMil" name="v-FreeMil" readonly>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="v-3col">
                                            <label for="">Cost per mile (LKR)</label>
                                            <input type="text" id="v-mileCost" name="v-mileCost" readonly>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="v-rows-container">
                                        <div class="v-rows rt1">
                                            <label for="">Passenger Count</label>
                                            <input type="text" id="v-passenger-count" name="v-passenger-count" readonly>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="v-rows rt2">
                                            <label for="">Luggage/Storage</label>
                                            <input type="text" id="v-luggage" name="v-luggage" readonly>
                                        </div>
                                        <!--<div class="v-rows rt3">
                                            <label for="">Air Conditioning</label>
                                            <input type="text" id="v-ac" name="v-ac" readonly>
                                        </div>-->
                                        <div class="v-rows rt4">
                                            <label for="">Gear System</label>
                                            <input type="text" id="v-gear" name="v-gear" readonly>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="v-rows rt5">
                                            <label for="">Fuel type</label>
                                            <input type="text" id="v-fuel" name="v-fuel" readonly>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <script>
                                        // Bring query parameters from PHP URL
                                        const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
                                        const vcode = urlParams.get('vcode');
                                        const model = urlParams.get('model');
                                        const freemil = urlParams.get('freemil');
                                        const milecost = urlParams.get('milecost');
                                        const passenger = urlParams.get('passenger');
                                        const luggage = urlParams.get('luggage');
                                        const gear = urlParams.get('gear');
                                        const fuel = urlParams.get('fuel');

                                        // Fill the form fields with taken values
                                        document.getElementById('v-code').value = vcode;
                                        document.getElementById('v-model').value = model;
                                        document.getElementById('v-FreeMil').value = freemil;
                                        document.getElementById('v-mileCost').value = milecost;
                                        document.getElementById('v-passenger-count').value = passenger;
                                        document.getElementById('v-luggage').value = luggage;
                                        document.getElementById('v-gear').value = gear;
                                        document.getElementById('v-fuel').value = fuel;
                                    </script>
                                    <div class="v-warning-msg">
                                        <p>
                                            Do .</p>
                                        <p>
                                            yyy.
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="v-contact">
                                        For any queries, please contact our fleet officer ::
                                        <b>011 - 234 5678</b>
                                    </div>
                                    <button type="button" onclick="form_buttonJump('vehicle')"> Next </button>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                            <div class="content content-1">
                                <div class="title">Enter reservation details</div>
                                <div class="outer-box">
                                    <div class="message">
                                        <p>
                                            If the vehicle has to be delivered to a location i.e the pick up
                                            and return locations are not the <b>Head Office</b>
                                            extra cost will be charge considering the distance between the
                                            relavant location/s and Head Office.
                                        </p>
                                        <br>
                                        <p>
                                            Charges will be applied to delays in return for every <b>30 minutes</b>.
                                            <br> Therefore, it is adviced to extend the retrun time in at least
                                            by 30 minutes.
                                            <br>These charges will depend on the vehicle that is been rented.
                                            You will be notified regarding these matters again, on pick up.
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="essentialForm">
                                        <div class="place">
                                            <label for="">Pickup Place</label>
                                            <div class="choosePlace">
                                                <input type="text" id="pickPlace" name="pickPlace"
                                                placeholder="Enter address" value="Head Office" required>
                                            </div>
                                            <label for="">Return Place</label>
                                            <div class="choosePlace">
                                                <input type="text" id="returnPlace" name="returnPlace"
                                                placeholder="Enter address" value="Head Office" required>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="dtHolder">
                                            <div class="dnt-wrapper">
                                                <div class="entDate">
                                                    <label>Pickup Date</label><br>
                                                    <input type="date" id="pickupDate" name="pickupDate" required>
                                                    <script>
                                                        var currentDate = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10);
                                                        document.getElementById("pickupDate").setAttribute("min", currentDate);
                                                    </script>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="entTime">
                                                    <label>Pickup Time</label><br>
                                                    <select title="pickupTime" id="pickupTime" name="pickupTime">
                                                        <option value="00:00">00:00</option>
                                                        <option value="00:30">00:30</option>
                                                    </select>
                                                    <script>
                                                        var select = document.getElementById('pickupTime');
                                                        select.selectedIndex = 18;
                                                    </script>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="dtHolder">
                                            <div class="dnt-wrapper">
                                                <div class="entDate">
                                                    <label>Return Date</label><br>
                                                    <input type="date" id="returnDate" name="returnDate" required>
                                                    <script>
                                                        document.getElementById("pickupDate").addEventListener("input", function() {
                                                            var pickupDateValue = document.getElementById("pickupDate").value;
                                                            
                                                            var nextDayTimestamp = new Date(pickupDateValue).getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
                                                            var nextDay = new Date(nextDayTimestamp);
                                                            var nextDayFormatted = nextDay.toISOString().split('T')[0];
                                                            
                                                            document.getElementById("returnDate").setAttribute("min", nextDayFormatted);
                                                        });
                                                    </script>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="entTime">
                                                    <label>Return Time</label><br>
                                                    <select title="returnTime" id="returnTime" name="returnTime">
                                                        <option value="00:00">00:00</option>
                                                        <option value="00:30">00:30</option>
                                                    </select>
                                                    <script>
                                                        var select = document.getElementById('returnTime');
                                                        select.selectedIndex = 20;
                                                    </script>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <button type="button" onclick="form_buttonJump('essentials')"> Next </button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="content content-2">
                                <div class="title">Enter customer details</div>
                                <!--<form>-->
                                    <div class="cus-details">
                                        <div class="cus-personal">
                                            <div class="cus-naming">
                                                <div class="titles">
                                                    <select title="honourific" name="prefix">
                                                        <option value="Mr.">Mr.</option>
                                                        <option value="Ms.">Ms.</option>
                                                    </select>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="fname">
                                                    <label for="fname">First Name</label>
                                                    <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="Eg: John" required>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="lname">
                                                    <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
                                                    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" placeholder="Eg: Wick" required>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="cus-oth-details">
                                                <div class="cus-nic">
                                                    <label for="nic">NIC</label>
                                                    <input type="text" id="nic" name="nicOpass" required
                                                        maxlength="12" onblur="nicCheck(this.value)">
                                                        
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="cus-age">
                                                    <label for="age">Age</label>
                                                    <input type="number" step="1" min="18" id="age" name="age" required minlength="3"
                                                        value="18">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="cus-email">
                                                <label for="email">Email</label>
                                                <input type="email" id="email" name="CUSemail" placeholder="Eg: johnwick40@hotmail.com"
                                                    required onblur="emailCheck(this.value)">
                                                    <!--pattern="[a-z0-9._+%-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$" -->
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="cus-drive">
                                            <div class="pilot">
                                                <input type="checkbox" name="driverNeed" id="driver-need" value="yes" onclick="LicenseReq()">
                                                <label for="driver-need">Driver needed</label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="lisence">
                                                <div class="cus-driv-lis">
                                                    <label for="dlNo">License No.</label>
                                                    <input type="text" maxlength="9" name="CUSdl" id="dlNo" required>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="cus-driv-lis">
                                                    <label for="dlExpDate">Expiration Date</label>
                                                    <input type="date" id="dlExpDate" name="CUSdlExp" required>
                                                    <script>
                                                        var currentDate = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10);
                                                        document.getElementById("dlExpDate").setAttribute("min", currentDate);
                                                    </script>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <button type="button" onclick="form_buttonJump('customer')"> Next </button>
                                <!--</form>-->
                            </div>
                            <div class="content content-4">
                                <div class="title">Enter payment details</div>
                                <!--<form>-->
                                    <div class="payDetail">
                                        <div class="p-card">
                                            <div class="p-cardNum">
                                                <label for="cardNumber">Card Number</label>
                                                <input type="text" name="cardNumber" id="cardNumber"
                                                    placeholder="xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx" minlength="15" maxlength="20"
                                                    oninput="cardTypeChecker(this.value)" required>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="cTypeImage">
                                                <img src="../images/unkowncard.png" id="cardType" alt="Unkown Card Type">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="p-holder">
                                                <label for="">Card Holder (Optional)</label>
                                                <input type="text" maxlength="12" id="crdHldr">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="p-needs">
                                            <div class="p-expDate">
                                                <label for="">Expiration Date</label>
                                                <input type="month" id="exMonth" name="exMonth" required>
                                                <script>
                                                    var today = new Date();
                                                    // Set the minimum month to the first day of next month
                                                    var minMonth = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth() + 1, 1);
                                                    var formattedMinMonth = minMonth.toISOString().slice(0, 7); // Format as yyyy-mm
                                                    document.getElementById("exMonth").setAttribute("min", formattedMinMonth);
                                                </script>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="p-cvv">
                                                <label for="">Enter CVV</label>
                                                <input type="password" maxlength="4" id="cvv" required>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="p-warn">
                                            <p>
                                                Note that the cardholder name should match the name on the card exactly, and
                                                should not include any titles, such as "Mr." or "Mrs.", or any additional
                                                information,
                                                such as a middle name or initial, unless it is included on the card.
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <button type="submit" name="bookNow"> Book Now </button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </section>
```

and this the php method in the form:

```
<?php
require './config.php';

function readData(){
    global $conn;
    if(isset($_POST['searchVehicle'])){
        if(isset($_POST['vehicle_selector'])) {
            $type = $_POST["vehicle_selector"];
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM vehicle where Type='$type' AND Availability='Available'";
            $result = $conn->query($sql);
            if($result->num_rows > 0){
                echo "<script>alert('Record found successfully!!')</script>";
                $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        
                // Assign column values to variables
                $vehicleCode = $row['Vehicle_Code'];
                $model = $row['Model'];
                $freeMilage = $row['Free_milage'];
                $mileCost = $row['Cost_per_mile'];
                $passengerCount = $row['Passenger_count'];
                $luggage = $row['Storage'];
                $gearSystem = $row['Gear_system'];
                $fuelType = $row['Fuel_type'];

                // Redirect to home.php with query parameters
                header("Location: home.php?vcode=$vehicleCode&model=$model&freemil=$freeMilage&milecost=$mileCost&passenger=$passengerCount&luggage=$luggage&gear=$gearSystem&fuel=$fuelType");
                exit();
            } else {
                echo "<script>alert('Error in search')</script>";
            }
        } else {
            echo "<script>alert('Something is wrong')</script>";
        }
        $conn->close();
    } else if(isset($_POST['bookNow'])){
        //get all neccessary values from fields
        $vCode = $_POST['v-code'];
        $price = $_POST['v-FreeMil'];

        //getting pickup/return details
        $pickupPlace = $_POST['pickPlace'];
        $pickupDate = $_POST['pickupDate'];
        $pickupTimer = $_POST['pickupTime'];

        $returnPlace = $_POST['returnPlace'];
        $returnDate = $_POST['returnDate'];
        $returnTime = $_POST['returnTime'];

        $prefix = $_POST['prefix'];
        $fname = $_POST['fname']; 
        $lname = $_POST['lname'];
        $nic = $_POST['nicOpass']; 
        $age = $_POST['age']; 
        $email = $_POST['CUSemail'];

        $driverNeed = $_POST['driverNeed'];
        $dlNo = $_POST['CUSdl']; 
        $dlExp = $_POST['CUSdlExp'];

        $currentDateTime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); //current DT

        //create customer
        $sql = "INSERT INTO Customer(CID,Prefix,Fname,Lname,Age,email,Nic_passport)
                VALUES ('','$prefix','$fname','$lname','$age','$email', '$nic')";
        //Enter run sql codes
        echo "<script>console.log('Running insertion [Customer]')</script>";
        runSQL($conn,$sql);

        //get CID
        $sql = "SELECT CID FROM Customer WHERE Nic_passport = '$nic'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
            $cid = $row['CID']; 
        } else {
            echo "<script>console.log('no results from table')</script>";
        }

        //free the result set (for memory purposes)
        mysqli_free_result($result);

        //insert customer_dl by adding DL details (regardless of driver is needed or not)
        //## improve to check if the CID is already exits in the table, if so: use UPDATE code
        $sql = "INSERT INTO customer_dl (CID,dlNo,dlExpDate)VALUES('$cid','$dlNo', '$dlExp')";
        echo "<script>console.log('Running insertion [Customer_DL]')</script>";
        runSQL($conn,$sql);

        //create payment
        $sql = "INSERT INTO Payment(PaymentID, Payment_datetime, Payment_type, Total_bill)
                VALUES ('','$currentDateTime', 'Card', '$price')";
        //Enter run sql codes
        echo "<script>console.log('Running insertion [Payment]')</script>";
        runSQL($conn,$sql);



        if($driverNeed == 'yes'){
            //find available driverID ----> set driver as not available
            $sql = "SELECT DriverID FROM Customer WHERE Availability = 'Available'";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
                $DrivID = $row['DriverID'];

                $sql="UPDATE Driver SET Availability = 'On Hire' WHERE DriverID='$DrivID'";
                echo "<script>console.log('Running update [Driver]')</script>";
                runSQL($conn,$sql);
            } else {
                echo "<script>console.log('no results from driver table')</script>";
            }
        }

        //get car ID -----> set its availability to NOT AVAILABLE
        $sql="UPDATE Vehicle SET Availability = 'Not Available' WHERE Vehicle_Code='$vCode'";
        echo "<script>console.log('Running update [Vehicle]')</script>";
        runSQL($conn,$sql);

        //create reservation (resID,Vcode,DriID,CusID,Pk detail,ret detail)
        $sql = "INSERT INTO reserve (ReservationID, CID, DriverID, Vehicle_Code, Reservation_datetime, 
        Pickup_date, Pickup_time, Pickup_location, Return_date, Return_time, Return_location)
        VALUES('', '$cid', '$DrivID', '$vCode', '$currentDateTime', 
                '$pickupDate', '$pickupPlace', '$pickupTime', 
                '$returnDate','$returnTime','$returnPlace')";
        echo "<script>console.log('Running insertion [reserve]')</script>";
        runSQL($conn,$sql);

        echo "<script>alert('ALL done!!')</script>";
    }
}

function runSQL($conn,$sql){
    if(mysqli_query($conn,$sql)){
        echo "<script>console.log('Record Inserted succesfully!!')</script>";
        //header("Location:index.php");
    }else{
        echo "<script>console.log('Error in insertion')</script>";
    }
}

readData();

?>
```

I have 2 submit buttons, and the searchVehicle named button working fine. It the bookNow button. it is not submitting the form. so i cant check what parts of my method file to edit.

- Tried removing the searchVehicle button
- clearing browser cache
- rechekcing button names
- editing 'else if' to 'elseif'
- changing postition of the bookNow button inside the form

Comment: why do i think that there is a mess with the forms.. you have two submit buttons in one form.. you have already commented the `<form>` tags which seperated the two forms.. **look out..**

Comment: Oh, that is due to: when i started to build this, I put 4 forms, for 4 tabs (content classes) and later realised I cant submit the entire 4 forms with a single button, unless I use a JS code that is beyond my current understanding. so to test if its works for a entire thing as  a single form, I commented all <form> and </form> tags in the middle.

Comment: Please clean up your code first. Then post it here. Only post the relevant portions that illustrate the problem and can be used to duplicate it.

Comment: You have _not_ commented out the `</form>` after the first "Next" button, so everything coming after that, is not part of any form any more.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for noticing it. I can't believe I missed that. its all good and well now